# Creating a JSON object to send back to Client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Thanks to everyone that has helped me this far.  I just have one last question and I think I can nix this learning project.

I want to create a JSON object Like so:

```
 [
     {name: 'xbox',
      upc: '1313413412',
      available_on: '12/31/18',
      properties: [
       {name: 'material',
        value: 'plastic'
       },
       {name: 'color',
        value: 'white'
       },
      ]
     },
     {name: 'nintendo',
      upc: '1313413412',
      available_on: '12/31/18',
      properties: [
       {name: 'material',
        value: 'plastic'
       },
       {name: 'color',
        value: 'black'
       },
      ]
     }
]
```

I have 3 tables product, properties, product_properties

I am joining them by doing this is my controller:

```
@products = Product.joins(:properties, :product_properties)

 @products.each do |product| 

 end
```

But I do not know where to go from here. I apologize for the newb question.  I am just trying to learn by doing.  My associations are set up correctly.

Schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2018_09_24_163027) do

  create_table "product_properties", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "value"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "product_id"
    t.integer "property_id"
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_product_properties_on_product_id"
    t.index ["property_id"], name: "index_product_properties_on_property_id"
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "upc"
    t.datetime "available_on"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "properties", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer "product_id"
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_properties_on_product_id"
  end

end
```

Thanks again for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to define models and set relationship between them. Using the tables from your example, the model classes will be:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_properties
  has_many :properties, through: :product_properties
end

class Property < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_properties
  has_many :products, through: :product_properties
end

class ProductProperty < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :property
end
```

(See more at:
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many)

Then, in your controller method

```
products = Product.joins(:properties, :product_properties).map do |product|
  {
    name: product.name,
    upc: product.upc,
    available_on: product.available_on.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"),
    properties: product.product_properties.map do |pr_property|
      {
        name: pr_property.property.name,
        value: pr_property.value
      }
    end
  }
end

render json: products
```

There is a waste space for query optimization though, however, I think it's fine for leaning project.

Comment: While this might not be an important place for optimizing queries, leaving N+1 queries should still be avoided.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that ```properties``` table has a field ```product_id```. What's the reason for that? Tables ```products``` and ```properties``` are already connected through the join table ```product_properties``` (which also holds ```value```).

Comment: @IlyaKonyukhov That is a mistake I need to fix.  Thank you for your answer as well!

Comment: @MarcinKołodziej Yup, thanks for the comment. Corrected my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
@products.map do |product|
  {
    name: product.name,
    properties: product.product_properties.map do |product_property|
      {
        name: product_property.property.name,
        value: product_property.value
      }
    end
  }
end.to_json
```

Feel free to put whatever attributes you need. You mentioned that you need a JSON, but you actually pasted a Ruby hash, I added a `.to_json` at the end.

Comment: That is great thanks!  Just one question.  I cant seem to get value: in that second map.  I thought with my associations I could just do something like property.product_properties.value.